# Unexpected change in Session value on form submission in Firefox

Tags: session

I am having an issue with PHP session in Firefox. There is a change in Session after each refresh/page reload. On other browsers, it is working fine.

In my WordPress template, I have initialized the session, comparing the post/session variables. A shortcode "inf_kit" defined in functions.php file will be called while executing "the_content()" function.

The shortcode defined in functions.php will call functions kit() and CSRF() which will set a session variable and add a hidden text field to the form, returned in my template. When I submit the form, I am getting a different value. In IE, Chrome is it OK. Does someone have any idea, where the issue might have?

---

**Code in template file**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["s_405"])){ 
    print_r($_SESSION);
    if($_SESSION['token_valid'] == $_POST['token_valid']) echo 'Good'; else echo 'issue'; 
} 

the_content(); 
?>
```

**Code in functions.php**

```
<?php
add_shortcode( 'inf_kit', 'kit');

function kit($atts){ 
    $form .= '<form name="kit" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" value="'.time().'" name="s_405"/>'
                . CSRF('valid'). 
                '</form>'; 
    return $form; 
} 

function CSRF($key){ 
    $tkn = sha1($key.uniqid(rand(), true)); 
    $_SESSION['token_'.$key] = $tkn; 
    return '<input type="hidden" name="token_'.$key.'" value="'.$tkn.'">'; 
}
?>
```